# Make: run code before a dependency is checked

Tags: makefile

I have a target that depends on an external library:

```
output.txt: library/build.txt main.txt
  cat library/build.txt main.txt >output.txt
```

(This is just an example, my actual makefile is much more complicated)

However, library/build.txt is generated by a separate makefile.
I need to run the library makefile (to potentially update build.txt) before make checks if library/build.txt is newer than output.txt

I could just have it run `$(MAKE) -C library`, every time, but I'm hoping to only call that when it is needed (meaning, when you try to make a target which depends on library/build.txt)

Is this possible? (maybe there's a way to get a list of dependencies and then run something if that list contains library/build.txt?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try things like :

```
FORCE:

library/build.txt: FORCE
    @echo make to build $@

output.txt: library/build.txt main.txt
    cat $^ > $@
```